# Creating a hive table without ROW FORMATTED comma delimated columns

Tags: hive

I have a `.CSV` comma delimited file

```
c1,c2,c3,c4
d1,d2,d3,d4
```

My requirement is to create an external hive table which has a single field named item and containing each row of my CSV file regardless of the comma delimited columns.

What is the hive query for create table which I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

Create hive table without specifying row formatted and hive defaults to **`cntrl+A(^A)`** delimiter.

- as your data is comma delimited so all data will be read by `single field name`.

**`Example:`**

```
create external table i(item string) location '<your_directory_path>';
```

Here **`item field`** will have all the data!